# Webservice Design: benefits of piping use-cases to URL rather than using search param's, or vice versa?

Tags: architecture, web-services, url

I've gotta build a webservice for employee information, and I'm trying to plan it out.

To clarify, we already have a REST-ish service for People and a separate REST-ish service for Companies.
This service will specifically be for the relationship between those two (all the data will be delivered from services to the data-consumers through a client (or clients) ).

Among other tasks, this service will need to:

1. retrieve all employers (company id's) for a given person ID
2. retrieve all employees (person id's) for a given company ID

I could see doing this a couple different ways.

1. Using search parameters could look *something* like:

   - `http://blah/employee/find?person_id=12345`
   - `http://blah/employee/find?company_id=9876`
2. Using the URL could look *something* like:

   - `http://blah/employee/find/employers?id=12345`
   - `http://blah/employee/find/employees?id=9876`

Taking the URL approach, I'd be able to specifically validate for a single parameter for each the *employer* and *employee* cases .. seems nice and clean, but quite fixed.
Taking the parameter approach seems like it's less-rigid/more-flexible, but then requires more data paths (if/else), and therefore the code can take longer to understand when future-me (or anyone else) comes back to it after it's been long forgotten.

What benefits might there be to going with once vs the other?
To me, the difference ***seems*** kinda arbitrary, but this is the first time I've got to make this decision.

Comment: Please share any suggestions for search terms or other ways I might find some insight here. I _have_ tried to research it, but all the search terms I've been able to think of thus far have proved unhelpful ... also, given that this is a question on best-practices in the planning stage of a project, naturally there will only be code of what's been tried available to share after this, once we get into the development stage of the project. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

I would just go with REST routes and in this case nested resources. This is somewhat similar to your second approach, only the IDs becomes part of the URL too. In this case your URLs would look like this:

```
http://blah/company/123/employees
http://blah/employees/789/companies
```

Though a lot depends on how your model works and how good your toolchain helps with RESTful routing. My suggestion comes from the view of a Rails programmer (and somehow the simple fact that REST is a good standard that consumers of your service should be able to understand easily)

For Rails in such a case there would be two controllers: companies and employees.
From the URL the requested controller would get the params. For the first URL params[:company_id] would be set to 123. And in the index action of the employees controller that would be called in that case I would simply do:

```
Company.find(params[:company_id]).employees
```

Vice versa for the second URL index in companies controller would do:

```
Employee.find(params[:employee_id]).companies
```

So there is not really any repetition. The tasks are clear for both controllers. The correct URL leads to the resource you want. Nesting the URLs defines dependencies between those resources. These are two quite distinct finctions and they actually **should** reside in different locations instead of trying to force them in a single location. Employees controller lists employees, companies controller lists companies. Can't really be clearer than that.

From here it may depend who the consumers of your service are. If they are developers, they should understand this (and chances are they already know how REST works). If they are not, you would have to get some kind of search page that lists the companies and allows them to select one (and similar for employees). Then this search page would link to the correct URL and they should not have to worry about what exactly that URL is anyway.

Comment: I _really_ like that suggestions. The one thing I'm trying to avoid, though, is ambiguity and/or replication. Companies can have 0-n people employed, and People can be employed by 0-n companies. Therefor, I'd have to either arbitrarily pick either the `company` or the `employee` service to implement the `employment` relationship (leaving people to guess where to find it), or I'd have to repeat myself and do both. Is that a bad thing? My **guess** is that, yeah, it is ... but I can't really back that up with any reasons. Thoughts?

Comment: @mOrloff update, maybe that makes it clearer. But details may depend on use cases of course.

Comment: Thanks-a-bunch for the update. Even though our "stuff" is put together quite differently than that, your details gave me a lightbulb moment ... I'll dig into it a little and see where it leads. By all means, keep the suggestions/thoughts coming! :)

Comment: Well if you already have a large service that's not RESTful at all it may be a bit stretching to change things that much. But once you get the hang to see things in terms of resources, a lot of organisational questions of that kind answer themselves. maybe [this book](http://info.apigee.com/Portals/62317/docs/web%20api.pdf) would help (I'm not related to the company, it just gives a nice overwiew)

Comment: Thanks for that link. I think that'll make a big difference for a long time to come :)

Comment: Just for clarity/posterity ... in my first comment above, I meant to say that I'd either have to pick the _"company"_ or the _**person**_ service ... not all people are required to be related to a company, so the employment relationship is optional.